# Repeated HTTP requests in Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

Say, I have more than 100 items in the database and the exact number not known. My back-end API will give me desired number of items if I provide the start item ID and the number of items required. Item ID is starting from 0 and increasing by 1.

I want to fetch them batch by batch (for example 10 items per batch) to process in the client side. After finishing processing one batch, I want to fetch the next batch.

What is the best way to achieve this using `RxJS` in my `Angular 2` project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to look into `Subject`s in RxJS. You can use one in an Angular2 Service to fetch the next page of results and push them to your UI using the subject's `.next(<value>)` api. Then expose a public observable to your components that they will subscribe to (or use an async pipe in a template) so that they can show the results.

The service that has the Subject can keep track of the number that you're at so it can have a `fetchNextPage` type of method on it that can be called to get the next batch of results pushed through the Subject and into your UI.

So something like this:

Injectable Service which has a Subject, probably methods like `fetch` and `fetchNextPage` to gather data, as well as an exposed `results` or something that is the Subject's `.asObservable()`

Component that gets the service injected, and then sets up a subscription to the service's `results` Observable. Call the service's `fetch` in your `ngOnInit` of your component, then when your UI deems it necessary, call `fetchNextPage` on the service to load more data.

Should work okay.